# How to upgrade from 10.04 without affecting touchpad settings?

Tags: upgrade, graphics, touchpad, resolution, macbook

I am using a Macbook Pro 8,1 (Early 2011) model. I tried installing Ubuntu 11.10, and had issues with the touchpad. I installed 10.04 LTR over the 11.10 install (I completely wiped the hard drive and then installed 10.04) and the touchpad has worked fine, however my graphics card (Intel HD Graphics 3000) is not working. It is only displaying a resolution of 1024x768 and I know my laptop can go higher than that. I read some forum posts online which said that I have the new Sandy Bridge processor and only 11.04 or newer would support it. Is there any way to upgrade from 10.04 to 11.04 and further without affecting my touchpad settings at all? Any help is appreciated-thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't upgrade from 10.04 to 11.10 directly, you need to first upgrade to 10.10, 11.04 and then 11.10. And if you have problems with the 11.10 if you make a clean install then you will have the same problems if you upgrade.

I suggest that you should wait a couple of weeks to see if the upgrades of 11.10 will improve the support for 11.10.

Comment: Is there a way to upgrade without affecting the touchpad settings at all? I was thinking maybe backing up anything that had to do with the touchpad and then restoring those files after the upgrade.

Comment: not really, well when you upgrade a system you get the new software  that replaces some of the old. If you have changed something so that the touchpad works then it **might** work if you upgrade. But if you just wait a couple of weeks to see when the support for 11.10 with support for your macbook pro. Of course you could just hope it works and do a system upgrade.